# Drupal 7 menu error

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, hook-menu

I writing custom module for Drupal 7 and got the following warning:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() в функции menu_unserialize() (строка 400 в файле /var/www/auth/includes/menu.inc).`

My hook_menu is here:

`function mnogomirauth2_menu() {
    $menu['tables/udkservers'] = array(
        'title' => 'udkserversTable', 
        'page callback' => '_menu_test', 
        'access arguments' => TRUE, 
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
    );


    return $menu;
}

function _menu_test()
{
    echo "test";
}`

Please, tell me, what's wrong with this code?

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Drupal API for [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)

> **"access arguments"**: An array of arguments to pass to the access
>   callback function, with path component substitution as described
>   above. If the access callback is inherited (see above), the access
>   arguments will be inherited with it, unless overridden in the child
>   menu item.

It seems that you have specified wrong argument `TRUE` for `access arguments`.

Answer (score 3):

**The below mentioned code will solve it:**

Before:

```
'access arguments' => TRUE,
```

After:

```
'access arguments' => array('Your Permission'), //array(TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that work is the following one.

```
function mnogomirauth2_menu() {
  $menu['tables/udkservers'] = array(
    'title' => 'udkserversTable', 
    'page callback' => '_menu_test', 
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
  );

  return $menu;
}
```

It's the access callback that can be a number. If it evaluates to `TRUE`, every user has access to the menu item; it it evaluates to `FALSE`, no user has access to the menu item.

#### References

- The documentation for [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)